# Split without using local files in gcloud shell

Tags: cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have a compressed gz file present in Google cloud storage  of size 12GB. We can't load more than 5 gigabytes directly to Bigquery. We need to split it. Can we split it without using any local file system. I tried using google cloud shell but seems we need to copy files/split files  to local file system first. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Please define GCS? BQ? gcloud? Your local abbreviations are not globally accepted.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the confusion-Edited question

Comment: I've voted to forward this question over to the WebApps sister site, as it is about a cloud application, and thus not quite on topic here.